# Captured Image is not stored in a specified path?

Tags: android

I am making one app to click images and save them in a specified folder in external storage.

Please follow my code below.

CaptureSignature.java

```
package com.capturesignatureactivity;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.util.Calendar;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
  import android.content.ContextWrapper;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.graphics.Bitmap;
  import android.graphics.Canvas;
  import android.graphics.Color;
   import android.graphics.Paint;
   import android.graphics.Path;
   import android.graphics.RectF;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.os.Environment;
   import android.provider.MediaStore.Images;
   import android.util.AttributeSet;
   import android.util.Log;
   import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
   import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
   import android.view.Window;
   import android.widget.Button;
   import android.widget.EditText;
   import android.widget.LinearLayout;
  import android.widget.Toast;

   public class CaptureSignature extends Activity {

   LinearLayout mContent;
   signature mSignature;
   Button mClear, mGetSign, mCancel;
public static String tempDir;
public int count = 1;
public String current = null;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
View mView;
File mypath;

   private String uniqueId;
   private EditText yourName;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.signature);

    tempDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir) + "/";
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File directory = cw.getDir(getResources().getString(R.string.external_dir), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    prepareDirectory();
    uniqueId = getTodaysDate() + "_" + getCurrentTime() + "_" + Math.random();
    current = uniqueId + ".png";
    mypath= new File(directory,current);


    mContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    mSignature = new signature(this, null);
    mSignature.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    mContent.addView(mSignature, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    mClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clear);
    mGetSign = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getsign);
    mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
    mCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
    mView = mContent;

    yourName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourName);

    mClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Cleared");
            mSignature.clear();
            mGetSign.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    mGetSign.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Saved");
            boolean error = captureSignature();
            if(!error){
                mView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                mSignature.save(mView);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putString("status", "done");
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtras(b);
                setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    });

    mCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Log.v("log_tag", "Panel Canceled");
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("status", "cancel");
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtras(b);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    }

     @Override
     protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.w("GetSignature", "onDestory");
    super.onDestroy();
    }

    private boolean captureSignature() {

    boolean error = false;
    String errorMessage = "";


    if(yourName.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        errorMessage = errorMessage + "Please enter your Name\n";
        error = true;
    }

    if(error){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 105, 50);
        toast.show();
    }

    return error;
    }

    private String getTodaysDate() {

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int todaysDate =     (c.get(Calendar.YEAR) * 10000) +
            ((c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) * 100) +
            (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    Log.w("DATE:",String.valueOf(todaysDate));
    return(String.valueOf(todaysDate));

    }

    private String getCurrentTime() {

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentTime =     (c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 10000) +
            (c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) * 100) +
            (c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    Log.w("TIME:",String.valueOf(currentTime));
    return(String.valueOf(currentTime));

    }


    private boolean prepareDirectory()
   {
    try
    {
        if (makedirs())
        {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Could not initiate File System.. Is Sdcard mounted properly?", 1000).show();
        return false;
    }
   }

   private boolean makedirs()
   {
    File tempdir = new File(tempDir);
    if (!tempdir.exists())
        tempdir.mkdirs();

    if (tempdir.isDirectory())
    {
        File[] files = tempdir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files)
        {
            if (!file.delete())
            {
                System.out.println("Failed to delete " + file);
            }
        }
    }
    return (tempdir.isDirectory());
    }

    public class signature extends View
   {
    private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 5f;
    private static final float HALF_STROKE_WIDTH = STROKE_WIDTH / 2;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path = new Path();

    private float lastTouchX;
    private float lastTouchY;
    private final RectF dirtyRect = new RectF();

    public signature(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
    }

    public void save(View v)
    {
        Log.v("log_tag", "Width: " + v.getWidth());
        Log.v("log_tag", "Height: " + v.getHeight());
        if(mBitmap == null)
        {
            mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (mContent.getWidth(), mContent.getHeight(),  Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);;
        }
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        try
        {
            FileOutputStream mFileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(mypath);

            v.draw(canvas);
            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, mFileOutStream);
            mFileOutStream.flush();
            mFileOutStream.close();
            String url = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mBitmap, "title", null);
            Log.v("log_tag","url: " + url);
            //In case you want to delete the file
            //boolean deleted = mypath.delete();
            //Log.v("log_tag","deleted: " + mypath.toString() + deleted);
            //If you want to convert the image to string use base64 converter

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.v("log_tag", e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void clear()
    {
        path.reset();
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        float eventX = event.getX();
        float eventY = event.getY();
        mGetSign.setEnabled(true);

        switch (event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(eventX, eventY);
                lastTouchX = eventX;
                lastTouchY = eventY;
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                resetDirtyRect(eventX, eventY);
                int historySize = event.getHistorySize();
                for (int i = 0; i < historySize; i++)
                {
                    float historicalX = event.getHistoricalX(i);
                    float historicalY = event.getHistoricalY(i);
                    expandDirtyRect(historicalX, historicalY);
                    path.lineTo(historicalX, historicalY);
                }
                path.lineTo(eventX, eventY);
                break;

            default:
                debug("Ignored touch event: " + event.toString());
                return false;
        }

        invalidate((int) (dirtyRect.left - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.top - HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.right + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH),
                (int) (dirtyRect.bottom + HALF_STROKE_WIDTH));

        lastTouchX = eventX;
        lastTouchY = eventY;

        return true;
    }

    private void debug(String string){
    }

    private void expandDirtyRect(float historicalX, float historicalY)
    {
        if (historicalX < dirtyRect.left)
        {
            dirtyRect.left = historicalX;
        }
        else if (historicalX > dirtyRect.right)
        {
            dirtyRect.right = historicalX;
        }

        if (historicalY < dirtyRect.top)
        {
            dirtyRect.top = historicalY;
        }
        else if (historicalY > dirtyRect.bottom)
        {
            dirtyRect.bottom = historicalY;
        }
    }

    private void resetDirtyRect(float eventX, float eventY)
    {
        dirtyRect.left = Math.min(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.right = Math.max(lastTouchX, eventX);
        dirtyRect.top = Math.min(lastTouchY, eventY);
        dirtyRect.bottom = Math.max(lastTouchY, eventY);
    }
}
}
```

My app runs well but the images are not stored in the specified directory. They are stored in DCIM folder.

Please guide.
Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
File sd = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File fichero = new File(sd, "signature.jpg");
```